# It is possible to get mod_rewrite urlBase server param via php?

Tags: php, apache

Could i get the apache mod_rewrite definition of urlbase via php scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the requested URL via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you can get the full path of the current PHP file via the magic constant `__FILE__`. From these 2 variables you could extrapolate `RewriteBase` however there may be situations where this is not possible.

It might help if you explain why you need access to `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply, i tried something similar i make a lookup for pathinfo, if not exists i explode SCRIPT_NAME by / array_pop script file and then implode again and replace to my request uri, actually seem to work, but i don't know how it will work in other environments

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround, if anyone knows any better i ll be glad to know, and i'll patch my file inmediately :P

```
$scriptName = explode("/",$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]);
array_pop($scriptName);
$folder = implode("/",$scriptName);
$pathInfo = str_replace($folder,"",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Thanks @rojoca for the hint!